# Android How GridView add static content

Tags: android, xml

[image: recyclerview]

I tried to layout this way, but it didn't work. What should I do? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid views just do the grid, they don't hold other views.  You have to make these ImageViews items in your grid.  That may mean using a multi-type gridview, one type for your normal items and one for your static items, with two different viewholders.